# Declaring a Dictionary<string,Func<>> with Functions already inside them c#

Tags: c#, dictionary, collection-initializer

First of all, I don't even know what to use when passing on 4 parameters but no return value, I'll just use Func as an example.

I do not want to use Dictionary.Add to insert my function, I want it to be inside while initializing the dictionary.

```
Dictionary<string, Func<int, int, int, int>> types = new Dictionary<string, 
{"Linear", Func<int, int, int, int>> //idk how to write this part
{ 
    code here
}}
```

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-a-dictionary-with-a-collection-initializer)?

Comment: Did you forget to write the method that can be called through this dictionary?  That is what is missing, its name.

Answer (score 3):

For a `Func` like the one you have in your question, this should work:

```
var myDict = new Dictionary<string, Func<int, int, int, int>>()
{
    {"Linear", (int a, int b, int c) => { return 0; } }
};
```

Note that you always need to have a `return` in your function.

If you want something that does not have a return value, you shouldn't use a `Func`, but an [`Action`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx) instead:

```
var myDict = new Dictionary<string, Action<int, int, int, int>>()
{
    {"Linear", (int a, int b, int c, int d) => { } }
};
```

Unlike functions, actions do not return anything.

Note the difference in meaning between `Action<int, int, int, int>` and `Func<int, int, int, int>`. In the former, the last int indicates the type of the 4th parameter, whereas in the latter it indicates the return type.